# How do I customize dual axis values?

Tags: tableau-api

I want to plot 2 variables in my worksheet.X variable vs Y variable. The Y variable is composed of 3 sub-variables y1,y2,y3 which when summed up result to Y. I have expressed y1,y2,y3 as percentages of Y say Y=45(100%) and y1=35%,y2=40%,y3=25%.How do I plot X vs Y with the Y axis value being 45 and not 100%?

I have been to plot the measure values of Y(y1,y2,y3) but now the axis values are automatically generated from 0 to 100%. What I want is the real axis values to be displayed 0 to 45.

I want the axis to be real values of Y(45) but the sub_variables (y1=35%,y2=40%,y3=25%)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things you can do here.

1. Click on the secondary axis and select "Synchronize axis".  This
   will ensure that the secondary axis is tied to the scope of the
   primary axis.
2. You can manually edit either/both axis by right clicking on them and setting the axis values manually.

Beyond this, it might be how you are setting up your viz.  If you could provide a picture/sample data it would be helpful.